# How to write hyphen between number and unit in an attribute (30-s acquisition) with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I think the title says it all. I browsed through the whole manual of `siunitx`, but I could not find an option allowing to write

```
30-s acquisition
```

with a single `\SI...` command (I could of course use a macro, but I guess this is not the point). I only found

```
\num{30}-\si{\second}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't follow: why are you trying to put a hyphen here?

Comment: The SI overlords will weep if you do this... :-)

Comment: That's why: http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/hyphens-with-numbers/

Comment: @bers If you look, units are used with the full name, not with the symbol. However, would you write “a 17-year old kid”? I hope not.

Comment: @egreg: So you would write "a 30-kilometers-per-hour speed limit" instead of "a 30-km/h speed limit"? I can think of more extreme examples if you like ;)

Comment: @Paul Gessler: thanks, I have no idea how I could miss that! You can even add that option to `\SI`, as in `\SI[number-unit-product=-]{30}{\second}`, so it stays local.

Comment: @bers: Using a hyphen between the quantity and the unit symbol is actively discouraged by the NIST style guide: "Even when the value of a quantity is used as an adjective, a space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol. ... Examples: a 1 m end gauge   but not:   a 1-m end gauge" http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/sec07.html

Comment: @bers don't do that; I deleted that part of my comment after seeing how it fails in an epic fashion within math mode.

Comment: @bers No, I'd write `\SI{30}{km/h} speed limit` in a technical document, but probably `30~km/h speed limit` in a novel.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks, VERY helpful. I did not know that! So I guess this ends the discussion at this point :)

Comment: Some style guides require this, e.g. AMS publications:
"It is AMS style to hyphenate number–unit pairs when they are used to modify a noun, for example, “10-km length; 5-day intervals”; we omit the hyphen in number–unit pairs that are not used as modifiers, for example, “the trench is 75 m deep; a height of 12 m.”"

https://www.ametsoc.org/index.cfm/ams/publications/author-information/formatting-and-manuscript-components/mathematical-formulas-units-and-time-and-date/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not advocate this at all, but if you must do it, I would propose a new command, `\SIadj`, for easy usage of both forms as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\SIadj}[2]{\SI[number-unit-product={\text{-}}]{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\SI{30}{\second}$ $\SIadj{30}{\second}$

\SI{30}{\second} \SIadj{30}{\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! While I will not use it (see also Jake's comment and egreg's later answer), this answers the question (and you were the first).

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how authoritative is the source you cite. But if you look closely, in the text only fully spelled out units are used, not their symbols.

At http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/sec07.html we find

> Even when the value of a quantity is used as an adjective, a space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol. (This rule recognizes that unit symbols are not like ordinary words or abbreviations but are mathematical entities, and that the value of a quantity should be expressed in a way that is as independent of language as possible—sees Secs. 7.6 and 7.10.3.)

At the surely authoritative source http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3.html we find (section 5.3.3)

> Even when the value of a quantity is used as an adjective, a space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol. Only when the name of the unit is spelled out would the ordinary rules of grammar apply, so that in English a hyphen would be used to separate the number from the unit.

Of course everything is possible and you can do what you want with

```
\SI[number-unit-product=\text{-}]{30}{s}
```

but you've been warned. `;-)`

Comment: Another thanks! Just to add this, `number-unit-separator` has been renamed to `number-unit-product` in `siunitx` version 2.2. It still works, but probably will not forever.